# Why is my form data not making it to the server?

Tags: javascript, html, express, routes

Hoping this is some sort of syntactical issue:

I'm testing on a local server sending data to a route as such:

```
<form onChange = {this.handleChange} onSubmit = {this.handleSubmission} action = "/articles/add">
```

I use a similar syntax to retrieve data using:

```
fetch("/api/user", options)
```

One is inserting data using HTML forms the other is retrieving data using JavaScript fetch.

I have verified the server is setup correctly but I am getting no response from the server in the insertion case.

I'm using Express routes as follows:

```
router.route('/add').get((req, res) => {
  console.log('/articles/add', 'route found', req);
});
```

**Update**

Is a method required on the form, the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) do not make it clear.

Comment: The method attribute is required if you are expecting the browser to do the submission and you want a method other than GET, the default. It's not clear what `handleSubmission` does, so I can't say whether it's necessary in this case.

Comment: I'm sending a form to the server.  It is about 5 fields.  Once the server gets the fields it will store them in a database.